# Batch file for Wget downloads

Tags: windows, batch

I've just written this to facilitate my Wget downloads and I was wondering if anyone can review it for me.

```
@ECHO off
CLS
IF [%1] == [] GOTO missing_arg
IF [%2] == [] GOTO missing_arg
IF NOT EXIST %2% GOTO bad_dir

ECHO About to download %1 to %2
ECHO.
PAUSE

CLS
CD /d "%2"
wget64 --execute robots=off --mirror --reject-regex '.*forum.*' --convert-links --adjust-extension --page-requisites --no-parent --progress=bar --no-check-certificate --show-progress --refer=http://google.com --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/4.0.1" %1
rundll32.exe cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub
ECHO Download complete
GOTO end

:missing_arg
rundll32.exe cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub
ECHO Correct syntax is "WGET <URL> <"Local Dir">"
GOTO end

:bad_dir
rundll32.exe cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub
ECHO Unable to find local directory for download - please check your input.

:end
```

Note: "Wget.bat" is the name of the above batch file in order to differentiate it from the actual program "Wget64.exe" which is called by the batch.

Please let me know what you think.

Comment: Looks good in overall. I'd only remove `pause`.

Comment: `rundll32.exe cmdext.dll,MessageBeepStub` - how many motherboards have speakers these days?

Comment: @Michael Harvey Try it - on a modern system it redirects through the Windows audio system to produce a standard audio alert.

Comment: @ipx Thanks for that - much appreciated.

Comment: @PiHard - doesn't on mine (Windows 10 21H1) using Windows Default sound scheme.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Interesting - of course I can't speak for your system, but it does on mine, which has the same version.